# Некорректное отображение ожидающих проверки «тревог» по поводу спама

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, тревоги

баг проявляется на странице «[сообщения, отмеченные пользователем имярек](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/178576)»

пока тревога находится на обработке/проверке, возле неё присутствует «статусная» отметка «на обработке»:

[image: на обработке]

**но** если это «тревога» **по поводу спама**, то этой отметки нет (отсутствует вообще какая бы то ни было отметка о текущем статусе):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

более того, в статистике, отображающейся на этой странице справа, происходит «провал» в подсчётах — эта, находящаяся на обработке/проверке «тревога» временно «теряется»:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у других типов «тревог» в таких случаях появляется строка:

> 1 — ожидает проверки

---

текущая статистика с моей страницы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**обновление**

аналогичная ситуация и с «оскорблениями»:

[image: рапорт про оскорбление]

[image: статистика оскорблений]

Comment: @NickVolynkin, как минимум в первом разделе статистики («отметки для привлечения внимания») — цифры сходятся. потому что там есть строка «ожидает проверки». а вот у сообщениий о спаме такой строки нет.

Comment: а у вас не отображается страница с моими «тревогами» (со ссылки на неё начинается вопрос)?

Comment: с вашими — нет. Пользователям недоступна чужая статистика тревог. Они раскрываются только при закрытии вопроса (там список закрывателей). А вот при удалении или отметке спамом — нет. Тревоги на комментариях — тоже. Думаю, это хорошо.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я добавил картинку со статистикой

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/15474/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php

Comment: нет, конечно не возражаю.

Comment: Проверьте пожалуйста, вроде должно быть исправлено. Даты к отметкам спама точно добавились.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, отметил спамом; http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/485790/178576

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, есть дата и есть статус «в ожидании».

Comment: то есть всё починили, верно?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну, будем надеяться, что с «оскорблениями» тоже всё в порядке. значит, починили.

Comment: вы там собственное сообщение как спам отметили?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, нет, только сам вопрос.

Comment: да, я про него. Снял отметку. У вас в истории это будет как «спорная», но это не «отклонена». Если бы я просто удалил вопрос, могли бы быть нехорошие последствия для аккаунта и ip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, дело в разных очередях. Оскорбления и спам отображаются в специальны очередях в панели модератора. Подчеркну, в отдельных очередях у *модератора*, то есть точно отличной от очереди проверок сообщества. Такая очередь имеет отдельный счетчик.

Comment: хорошо, пусть с отображением статистики — непреодолимые технические (?) трудности. но почему *состояние* не отображается? ведь оно точно известно — *после* проверки исправно **добавляется** вердикт: «полезный» либо «спорный» (возможно, есть и другие, но среди моих «тревог» других вердиктов не встречается).